# Shopify draft order issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, shopify

I have create draft order using Shopify Draft order api in php via ajax call.

in ajax response I get one url and redirect on it www.mysite.com/17875421/invoices/280fa46bee5ca183da7e774457522428.
url is correct and all things goes well user able to see the checkout page with correct order data.

But sometime shopify show the 404 page rather than checkout page.

after showing the 404 page if I refresh the page by simple heating F5 Key than all works fine.

I can't understand why this happening.

would someone help me to solve and find the reason why this things happening ?

My ajax call function as below

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: AjaxUrl,
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        formData
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        showLoader();
    },
    complete: function () {
        hideLoader();
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response['result'] == 'success') {
            window.location = response['invoice_url'];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: My only guess is either there may be a cache issue which shows u this 404 page or you are calling return url too early in the success.

Comment: Try to add some delay in your location redirect. Just a guess.

Comment: @CodeThing I tried it, added 2 second delay before redirecting. however problem not resolved.

Comment: In this case i recommend you to consult with the shopify support, as you don't have any problem with the code and you are getting `invoice_url` correctly.

Comment: @Code Thing Thanks I contacted them and they told me that your url is dead I replied them than why it will live after refresh and they not suggest me anything after I post here.. Could you please up vote my question if it is genuine

Comment: Sorry Sachine, this has nothing to do with the SO here. If there was a problem with the code or intergration, then it can be considered. But the real problem lies inside the shopify. They have to answer you that why it is showing 404 and it works after page refresh. HTH

Comment: I agreed But They don't give any valid way. I hate the support of shopify. lets me try again to contact them. and one thing notice its arise when some one click on button (that call my js function) quickly on half or less reload the page.